# Memory allocation for pointer to array and array of pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Below is the part of code I am stuck on. I want to dynamically allocate memory for

- Pointer to array
- Array of pointers

I am getting several error messages like invalid conversion from int * to int and so on.

**Pointer to array**

```
int (*array)[nrows][ncolumns];
array = (int*)malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(int));


printf("\n Enter the elements:\n");

for(i=0; i<nrows; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<ncolumns; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", array[i][j]);   
    }
}

printf("Entered array is :\n\n");

for(i = 0;i<nrows; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<ncolumns; j++)
    {
        if(j== ncolumns-1)
        {
            printf("%d \n", *array[i][j]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d", *array[i][j]);
        }
```

**Array of pointers**

```
int *array[nrows][ncolumns];
array[nrows][ncolumns] = (int*)malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(int));

printf("Enter elements:\n");

for(i = 0; i<nrows; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<ncolumns;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);


    }
}


printf("Entered array is: \n");
for(i = 0; i<nrows; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<ncolumns;j++)
    {
        if(j == ncolumns-1)
        {
            printf("%d \n",array[i][j]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d \t",array[i][j]);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you start with one-dimensional arrays until you're comfortable with the difference between arrays and pointers, and the difference beween a pointer to an array and a pointer to an array's first element. Also, that you stay away from `malloc`ing these things until you can write the code without it.

Comment: Thanks. But actually I don't have that much time. I have to correct it in 1 hour. Please help me out. Is the memory allocation part correct?

Comment: @Sujit Well, you should have began studying earlier. Hints: In 1), `array[i]` is a two-dimensional array, `array[i][j]` is a one-dimensional array. In 2), `array[i][j]` is an (uninitialised) pointer, not an `int`.

Comment: I can write both programs without using malloc. But this malloc thing has ruined my mind. :(

Comment: in 2> when i omit the malloc line, its working fine. how?

Comment: @Sujit `array[nrows][ncolumns]` is an element outside the array; assigning to it is undefined.

Comment: An option not mentioned yet is `int (*array)[ncolumns] = malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @M.M , I have tried that option 3hrs ago. didn't work. May be my method was wrong. can u elaborate it?

Comment: @Sujit there's not any more to it really. Use it the same as if you had written `int array[nrows][ncolumns];`. post the code that isn't working if you have trouble

Comment: @M.M   I just replaced malloc line with:-   int (*array)[ncolumns] = malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(int));       Rest all lines were the same as posted in the question.

Comment: @Sujit you also need to fix the bugs in your use of scanf and printf, it should be `scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);` and `printf("%d", array[i][j]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1> pointer to array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int nrows    = 3;
    int ncolumns = 4;
    int i, j;

    int (*array)[nrows][ncolumns];//do you want <<int (*array)[ncolumns]>> ?
    //like as int src[nrows][ncolumns]; array = &src;
    array = malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(int));//(int*) : type mismatch

    printf("\nEnter the elements:\n");

    for(i = 0; i<nrows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<ncolumns; j++){
            scanf("%d", &(*array)[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Entered array is :\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i<nrows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<ncolumns; j++){
            if(j != 0)
                putchar(' ');
            printf("%d", (*array)[i][j]);//need ( )
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

---

2> Array of pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int nrows   = 3;
    int ncolumns = 4;
    int i, j;

    int *array[nrows][ncolumns];
    int *src = (int*)malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(int));//no need (int*)

    printf("Enter elements:\n");

    for(i = 0; i<nrows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<ncolumns;j++){
            array[i][j] = &src[ i * ncolumns + j];//pointer pointed to entity (src[ i * ncolumns + j])
            scanf("%d", array[i][j]);//type of array[i][j] is int *
        }
    }

    printf("Entered array is: \n");
    for(i = 0; i<nrows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<ncolumns; j++){
            if(j != 0)
                putchar(' ');
            printf("%d", *array[i][j]);//need * for dereference
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    free(src);
    return 0;
}
```

---

3> option

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int nrows    = 3;
    int ncolumns = 4;
    int i, j;

    int (*array)[ncolumns];
    array = (int (*)[ncolumns])malloc(nrows * sizeof(*array));//sizeof(*array) : sizeof(int[ncolumns])

    printf("\nEnter the elements:\n");

    for(i = 0; i<nrows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<ncolumns; j++){
            scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Entered array is :\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i<nrows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<ncolumns; j++){
            if(j != 0)
                putchar(' ');
            printf("%d", array[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It really helped.    Though, in 1st program, M still getting the 'Type conversion' error..

Comment: @Sujit Perhaps you are using C++ compiler as C compiler. (cast from `void *` no need in C ), try `array = (int (*)[nrows][ncolumns])malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(int));`

Comment: I am using Dev-C++ compiler.  Thanks once again. Now both progrmas are running well.

Comment: Means?  Where to add & which option?

Comment: @Sujit add example of `3> option`.  M.M's comment for `int (*array)[ncolumns] `

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your edit. 3rd option is also working. (though it confused me a lot ). I have one question, why do we need typecasting before malloc here?

Comment: @Sujit because C++ isn't allow implicit conversion from `void *`.

Comment: For allocating `int (*array)[nrows][ncolumns];` why not just do `array = malloc(sizeof *array);`?

Comment: All these casts are not needed nor recommended in C: http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/694576

Comment: _why not just do..._ It did not change so as not to unnecessarily confusing. (at option do it)

Comment: @alk     Thats not working. Shows error: Invalid conversion.

Comment: Ok, so you use a C++ compiler, why do you tag your question C though? C and C++ are *not* the same language.

Comment: @alk   yes I am using Dev C++ compiler , but my code is in C language not C++ .

Comment: If you use C++ compiler to compile code is is treated as C++ code, along with all issues popping up being C++ issues (by definition). To have the code treated a C code *use a C compiler*.